# dynamic_cast issues: typeid object is not equal, but name is equal

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, typeid

I found that `dynamic_cast` didn't work in a situation where I expected it to, and looking at the `typeid` of the objects at runtime has made the situation even less clear. I just want a cast from base to derived, and I can't figure out why it's not working.

I have a class structure something like this:

```
class BoundaryCondition {
public:
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;

    virtual ~BoundaryCondition() { /* * */ }
}

class ReflectingBc : BoundaryCondition {
public:
    virtual void DoSomething();
}

class MarshakBc : BoundaryCondition {
public:
    virtual void DoSomething();

    MarshakBc(double value);

    void changeValueLaterOn(double value);
private:
    double value_;
}
```

I have (essentially) a `std::vector<BoundaryCondition*>` that represents boundary conditions in parts of the problem. I want to be able to take that `vector` and, for all `MarshakBc` objects inside it, call `changeValueLaterOn`. So I have a loop that looks like

```
for (std::vector<BoundaryCondition*>::iterator bc = bcPtrs_.begin();
        bc != bcPtrs_.end(); ++bc)
{
    if (std::string(typeid(MarshakBc).name()) == std::string(typeid(**bc).name()) )
    {
        std::cerr << "SAME! ";
    }

    if (typeid(MarshakBc) != typeid(**bc))
    {
        std::cerr << "NOT SAME ";
    }
    MarshakBc* thisBc = dynamic_cast<MarshakBc*>( &( **bc ) );
    if (thisBc == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "...nothing\n";
        continue;
    }
    thisBc->changeValueLaterOn( 1.23);
    std::cerr << "...set!\n";
}
```

If my vector contains a `ReflectingBc*`, then a `MarshakBc*`, my output looks like:

```
NOT SAME ...nothing
SAME! NOT SAME ...nothing
```

Am I misunderstanding something about `dynamic_cast` and `typeid`?

[The actual situation is more complicated than this because the definition of `BoundaryCondition` is in a different translation unit than the above code, and templates and such are involved, but the above code is very representative of what I'm doing and the result I'm getting.]

---

### More details

Here is my actual routine, which is used inside a functor, and `LoAnisoBc` is the derived class and `BoundaryConditionT` is the base class:

```
template<class SnTraits_T, class LoTraits_T>
void FillLoAnisoBcs<SnTraits_T, LoTraits_T>::operator() (
        const BoundaryFaceT& bf,
        BoundaryConditionT& bc)
{
    std::cerr << "Want " << typeid(LoAnisoBc).name() << "\n";
    std::cerr << "Chkg " << typeid(bc).name() << "\n";

    if (std::string(typeid(LoAnisoBc).name()) == std::string(typeid(bc).name()) )
    {
        std::cerr << " SAME!";
    }

    if (!(typeid(LoAnisoBc) == typeid(bc))) {
        std::cerr << "...nothing\n";
    }

    // if we're not an "anisotropic BC", don't do anything
    LoAnisoBc* anisoBc = dynamic_cast<LoAnisoBc*>( &bc );
    if (anisoBc == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "...nothing\n";
        return;
    }

    anisoBc->setFCoeff( fCoeff_ );
    std::cerr << "; set fCoeff = " << fCoeff_ << "\n";
}
```

And here's the output

```
Want N6detLib17cellDiffusionOned28AnisotropicBoundaryConditionE
Chkg N6detLib17cellDiffusionOned27ReflectingBoundaryConditionE
NOT SAME...nothing
Want N6detLib17cellDiffusionOned28AnisotropicBoundaryConditionE
Chkg N6detLib17cellDiffusionOned28AnisotropicBoundaryConditionE
SAME! NOT SAME...nothing
```

---

So the `bcPtrs_` structure and the boundary conditions are in one dynamic library (so it's one module in Python), and the instantiation of `FillLoAnisoBcs` is in another dynamic library. Erik suggests this as the probable issue and I agree.

Comment: It should work.  Could you provide a full test case showing the problem -- I fear the precise way you complete it is pertinent -- and additional informations such as tool chain and if the different C.U. are in different dynamic libraries.

Comment: How do you populate the vector? Show us the code...

Comment: hmm.. not sure how this could work, `bc` is an iterator, when you de-reference the iterator your get a pointer to `BoundaryCondition`, the `typeid` of that *pointer* would be `BoundaryCondition` AFAIK...

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my demo. See the real thing. @Nawaz: all of the relevant code would be thousands of lines. This is about as close as I can give you.

Comment: @Seth Johnson: I guess you've hit a case of 18.5.1/1: "The names, encoding rule, and collating sequence for types are all unspecified
and may differ between programs." - you're not really supposed to compare the names as there's no guarantees, but the behavior you see is still odd. Does it change if you e.g. use `typeid(AnisotropicBoundaryCondition) .name()` in the TU defining `AnisotropicBoundaryCondition` ?

Comment: @Erik: I just tried that, and the result is the same: the names are identical, the types should be identical, but the typeid comparison fails.

Comment: @Seth Johnson: This isn't a case of crossing library boundaries? DLL/.so?

Comment: @Erik: actually, that's probably it. I'm running this using Python wrappers. What are the implications and how can I get around this?

Comment: @Seth Johnson: I don't think you can get around it if base and derived are in different libraries

Comment: @Seth Johnson: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819114/when-can-typeid-return-different-type-info-instances-for-same-type may help

Comment: @Erik: Base and derived are in the same library, but the code that operates on them is in a different library. If you post your answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Seth Johnson: On linux, `-rdynamic` may fix that - you're outside my practical experience now :P

Comment: What compiler/version and platform are you running this in?

Comment: This is on a mac (10.6.x) with g++ 4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeid` behaves strangely when you're crossing library boundaries - See e.g. [When can typeid return different type_info instances for same type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819114/when-can-typeid-return-different-type-info-instances-for-same-type) for some cases. In particular, on linux you will need `-rdynamic` to ensure that type info objects from a library aren't removed, and thus inaccessible to the executable using the library.

My best guess at an explanation:

In the executable, where you see the `LoAnisoBc` definition, a `type_info` instance for `LoAnisoBc` exists. In the library, where `LoAnisoBc` "belongs", another `type_info` instance exists. `type_info`'s `operator==` is likely implemented as a simple pointer comparison. So, when you get typeid of the static `LoAnisoBc` expression you get the executable instance, whereas the reference produces the library instance - same name but not same instance.

Comment: Looking at **[type.info]** in n3242 the implementation of `operator==` should normally return true if and only if the two objects being compared are the same (minus cv-qualification and reference). There is no guarantee that comparing the addresses of the `type_info` objects would work, but it seems to me that `operator==` should... Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Matthieu M. As I said, I was guessing on the implementation the OP's toolchain uses - it would explain the behavior. There could definitely be other explanations as well, I just found this one likely, that type_info for *his* library compares pointers as the internal implementation of `op==` (The pointers of the backend structure, not the front type_info class).

Comment: I understand, I'm just trying to see whether it conforms to the standard or not. It seem to me it does not... but I'm far from being a standardista.

Comment: @Matthieu M. Consider a singleton structure containing a.o. the name literal and whatever other info is needed for a type - generated by the compiler. Then a type_info instance which contains only a pointer to this shared structure (produced by typeid). That'd give compliant behavior, and could produce the symptoms the OP sees when crossing lib boundaries - comparing the pointers to the *different* backend structures.

Comment: I remember lurking through some boost header, that they needed to work around that particular problem too, when to use normal == compare and when to compare the names directly. Should be able to find out which compilers don't work with the normal way by looking at the defines.