# boost::any typeid optimization for C++11

Tags: c++, boost, stl, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When can typeid return different type_info instances for same type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819114/when-can-typeid-return-different-type-info-instances-for-same-type)

If I change the `operand->type() == typeid(ValueType)` line below into `&operand->type() == &typeid(ValueType)`, the code still works with gcc and takes up less space in the executable (and did so for many years now), but does the C++11 standard give any guarantees, that this optimization should work across different compilers?

```
template<typename ValueType>
ValueType * any_cast(any * operand)
{
    return operand && 
#ifdef BOOST_AUX_ANY_TYPE_ID_NAME
        std::strcmp(operand->type().name(), typeid(ValueType).name()) == 0
#else
        operand->type() == typeid(ValueType)
#endif
        ? &static_cast<any::holder<ValueType> *>(operand->content)->held
        : 0;
}
```

Comment: That's technically a C++03 question, and this one is C++11. Editing to make it explicitly not a duplicate (answer is still correct)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not guaranteed. This assert may trigger:

```
assert(&typeid(int) == &typeid(int));
```

While it would take a pretty stupid compiler to make that fire, it could happen. In practice, it will only fail when typeid's are being compared across dynamic library boundaries:

```
assert(&typeid_of_int_in_lib1() == &typeid_of_int_in_lib2());
```

This will almost certainly trigger.

Comment: found this post, the assert might fire in Windows, but might not in linux: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819114/when-can-typeid-return-different-type-info-instances-for-same-type)

Comment: @user1095108: Ah, duplicate after all. :)

Comment: Not entirely, people might still hack their any.hpp, if they link statically.

Comment: it will only fail in linux if you compile the class with hidden visibility.