# Safest way for unique type identification in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, typeid

Somewhere during the forming of the new standard there was a promise for easier `type_info` usage, which among others resulted in the implementation of `hash_code`. Implementing a reflection system in C++11 however I ran into a problem with unique type identification again.

I need:

1. Something that will allow me extraction from a type using typeid a unique identifier
2. The unique identifier needs to be able to be used in a key/value container
3. The identifier does not need to be portable, nor even the same between program executions

Note that I do not need persistence between program exeutions. As it seems:

1. `.name()` is completely useless, because the standard gives no guarantees on it whatsoever.
2. `.hash_code()` is also useless because it's not guaranteed to be unique
3. Taking a pointer to the `type_info` object won't work everywhere (across DLL's for example)
4. Only `.before()` seems to be useful - although I don't know if it wouldn't suffer from the same problem as #3

Even if `.before()` is to be used, then we can use `map`, while I would prefer to use `unordered_map`.

```
struct compare_type_info {
    bool operator ()(const type_info* a, const type_info* b) const {
        return a->before(*b);
    }
};
std::map<const type_info*, X, compare_type_info> map;
m[&typeid(int)] = something;
```

Is the above safe for collision? Does the ordering operator guarantee overwrite of !< and !> values?

Is there a way to solve this problem without hash collision risk?

In terms of rolling up my own type system, I already do that, but `typeid` solves problems with giving the proper final type from a base type (inheritance) and I do not want to add any fields to my classes (the type system is "external").

Even in C++11 are we still screwed? :/

Comment: "*there was a promise for easier type_info usage*" No, there was not. And that's not what `hash_code` is for.

Comment: Also, is there some reason you can't use `type_info` itself?

Comment: @Nicol, I want to tie in more information about the type (reflection).

Comment: I got that part. Why can't you use `type_info` for that? Why can't you use it as your key in an `unordered_map`?

Comment: I have a object* pointer - I want to access my type database, so I need to get out of the object* pointer the real type pointer (derived*), AFAIR there's no other way than through typeid(). So I want an index of typeid -> my type info. However, the typeinfo may be expanded during execution, so it can't have duplicates, and must always be returnable.

Comment: "*the typeinfo may be expanded during execution*" What do you mean by that?

Comment: My own typeinfo can be expanded, by other modules injecting more info about how to process that type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [use `std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index), which is constructable from a `std::type_info`. These are fully ordered, implementing all of the relational operations. A `type_index` is even implicitly convertible from `type_info`.

Comment: That *seems* to be what I'm looking for... but looking through the last draft it seems the standard doesn't make any guarantees on it's uniqueness?

Comment: Ergo - if for type A and type B, type A = type B, does that guarantee that operator==(A,B) equals true even in different DLLs?

Comment: The Standard says absolutely nothing about "different DLLs."  But I would expect them to work that way.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't say anything about the uniqueness of type_info instances, and that's the best example I can provide that makes them not unique :/.

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz: "*it doesn't say anything about the uniqueness of type_info instances*" Why would it? The *contents* of `type_info` are what matter. If two type_info instances refer to the same type, then they compare equal. If not, then they will have some arbitrary ordering. What more do you want?

Comment: I want to uniquely identify every type, so I can add meta-information to it.

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz: And how does `type_info` not accomplish that? Where in the standard does it allow two `type_info` objects that refer to different types to compare equal?

Comment: AFAIK, it doesn't disallow two typeid calls of returning different type_info objects.

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz: Wait. The standard very clearly says, for `operator==`, "`true` if the two values describe the same type." And you interpret this as somehow not identifying the type?

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz You don't need uniqueness and none of `std::type_info` or `std::type_index` rely on it.

Comment: @Nicol, in most other boolean returns in the standard that is succeeded by "false otherwise". Not the case here, but I guess that's as far as I can get a guarantee. See this discussion - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819114/when-can-typeid-return-different-type-info-instances-for-same-type?rq=1

Comment: Question is - does that weakness go over to operator==? Will it mess up the unordered_map based on type_index'es?

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz: "*in most other boolean returns in the standard that is succeeded by "false otherwise"*" No, in *many* other booleans, it says that. In some, it does not. For example, `std::thread`'s `operator==` doesn't say that.

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz: "*See this discussion*" That discussion is completely irrelevant. Where the memory for a particular type_info instance comes from does not matter. What matters is what the standard says happens when they compare equal.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for the patience :)